# Change of eigenvalues under near orthogonal matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, orthogonal-matrices, matrix-analysis

Let $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ be positive definite diagonal matrices. Let $\Phi\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$ satisfy $\text{rank}(\Phi) = n \leq d$ and be such that $\Phi\Phi^T = I_n$. When $d = n$, $\Phi$ is orthonormal and hence
$$\lambda_i(\Phi A\Phi^T) - \lambda_i(\Phi B\Phi^T) = \lambda_i(A) - \lambda_i(B),$$
where $\lambda_i(\cdot)$ denotes the $i^{\text{th}}$ largest eigenvalue.
If $n<d$, is it possible to express (or bound)
$$ \lambda_i(\Phi A\Phi^T) - \lambda_i(\Phi B\Phi^T)$$
in terms of $\lambda_i(A) - \lambda_i(B)$ and $d-n$ ?

Comment: @viadye    You changed the question.  I don' t think that $\lambda_1(A-B) = \lambda_1(A) - \lambda_1(B)$.

Comment: @viadye   For example, choose $$A=\left(\begin{matrix} 3 & 0 \\0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right)$$ and $$B=\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\0 & 2 \end{matrix}\right).$$  Then $\lambda_1(A) = 3$, $\lambda_1(B) = 2$, $\lambda_1(A-B) = 2$.

Comment: Thank you, @irchans. Fixed the error in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if
$$A=\left(\begin{matrix} a_1 & 0 \\ 0 & a_2 \end{matrix}\right)$$
where $a_1>a_2>0$, and $\Phi = (0\  1)$, then $\lambda_1(A) = a_1$ and
$$\lambda_1(\Phi A \Phi^T + \alpha) = \Phi A \Phi^T + \alpha = a_2 + \alpha.$$

So, $$\lambda_1(\Phi A \Phi^T + \alpha) - \lambda_1(A) = a_2 +\alpha - a_1$$
which cannot be bounded by a function of just $\lambda_1(A)=a_1, \alpha, d,$ and $n$.

Comment: I think that  $$| \lambda_i(\Phi A \Phi^T + \alpha I_n) - \lambda_i(A)|  \leq |\alpha| + \max( \lambda_j(A) - \lambda_i(A), \lambda_i(A) -\lambda_k(A) )$$ where $j=max(1, i- (d-n))$ and $k=min(d, i+(d-n))$.

Comment: Something like this feels correct. When one does simulations for, for example $d = 100$, $n = 90$, then one finds that many of the eigenvalues have a difference of exactly $\alpha$.